# Can creating and returning a disposable object from a static class method cause memory leaks?

Tags: c#, .net-core, static-methods, idisposable, static-classes

I've noticed a windows service taking a lot of memory and am trying to get to the bottom of the issue. I noticed that we have a static class containing a static method which is in charge of creating and returning an SftpClient instance, which implements IDisposable. Code for this static class is below.

```
public static class FTPHelper
{
    public static SftpClient CreateFTPClient(string ftpURL, string username, string password, string keyFilePath)
    {
        var privateKey = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyFilePath) ? new PrivateKeyFile(keyFilePath, password) : null;
        var client = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyFilePath)? new SftpClient(ftpURL, username, new[] { privateKey }):
                        new SftpClient(ftpURL, 22, username, password);
        return client;
    }
}
```

We are then calling this method in other parts of the service as below

```
using var ftpClient = FTPHelper.CreateFTPClient(
                ftpUrl,
                ftpUsername,
                ftpPassword,
                ftpKeyFilePath);
```

My question is could the above setup be causing a memory leak? As per the last screenshot, the "using" keyword is being used, however I have read that static objects and everything they reference are not collected by the Garbage collector, so is this the case here?

Comment: No, your setup should not be causing a memory leak. The FTPHelper is a static class, yes, but it doesn't hold any static state - it's just a helper that produces new instances of SftpClient. The SftpClient instances themselves are not static, and are disposed properly via the using statement. Each call to CreateFTPClient creates a new SftpClient and then, because of the using statement, when execution leaves the block, Dispose will be called on the SftpClient, freeing up any resources it holds.

Comment: You should look for other parts of the code where:

1. Objects implementing IDisposable are not being disposed of correctly. That is, they are not inside a using block or explicitly disposed of.
2. Large collections or other data structures are being stored statically and not released when no longer needed.
3. Event handlers not being unregistered, which can also cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is could the above setup be causing a memory leak?

No, creating objects in a static method is perfectly fine. And disposing objects with `using` is also perfectly correct.

> however I have read that static objects and everything they reference are not collected by the Garbage collector, so is this the case here

This applies to static *objects*, but you only have a static *method*. Static methods are perfectly fine, at least if they do not use any static fields/objects.

So this would be bad, for many reasons:

```
public static class FTPHelper
{
    public static SftpClient client; // BAD!
    public static SftpClient CreateFTPClient(string ftpURL, string username, string password, string keyFilePath)
    {
        var privateKey = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyFilePath) ? new PrivateKeyFile(keyFilePath, password) : null;
        client = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyFilePath)? new SftpClient(ftpURL, username, new[] { privateKey }):
                        new SftpClient(ftpURL, 22, username, password);
        return client;
    }
}
```

If you have a memory leak you should use a [memory profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2022) to try figure out what objects are leaking. A common culprit is event registrations that do not unregister, especially if you have any static events. Another common reason is not disposing things that are disposable.

But your example looks just fine, whatever your problem is it is most likely in some other piece of code.

Comment: thanks for the info, will look into the memory profiler